# Fighting with APIs in Python

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I am trying to learn how to use APIs for financial analysis.

I have the following simple code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from pandas_datareader import data as wb

PG = wb.DataReader('PG', data_source = 'morningstar', start = '1995-01-01')
```

So, I am trying to extract PandG data from morningstar. The **problem** is that I get back the following message:

```
    ImmediateDeprecationError: 
Morningstar has been immediately deprecated due to large breaks in the API without the
introduction of a stable replacement. Pull Requests to re-enable these data
connectors are welcome.
```

I tried the same with Google but I failed. Is there something wrong in my code or is it something else?

I do have some csv files, how can I use them as source in the code above?

Below you can see what my codes gives back:
 [image]

Comment: Doesn't seem like an issue within the code, rather the 3rd party API had been changed without the necessary changes in the module which would compensate. Similar to [this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/487)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, I would recommend using other sources such as AlphaVantage, Quandl, or IEX. The simplest is IEX, which does not require an API key. The reason for that is because maybe 
MorningStar has discontinued their API services. MorningStar is a less-known API. Or Python won't run it because it is not stable enough. Google has also disabled their API services.

Comment: Thanks, I searched a bit about Quandl but it gives me back an error with message:  The Quandl API key must be provided either through the api_key variable or through the environmental variable QUANDL_API_KEY.

Answer (score 1):

Apperently you have to change from google finance to another.

https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/604

Comment: It is weird, I though Yahoo! is the API that is supposed to not work!

Answer (score 1):

Use single responsibility principle. Create a DataFetcher class and expose a public method which can retrieve you data. For now, this DataFetcher class would extract information from the CSV file.
Use DataFetcher class in your actual place.

Once you are confident enough, you can switch the CSV file logic to API request.

Comment: Hi, can you please give me a sample code since I am a new?

Comment: The API is very clearly reporting that it is completely broken and gone indefinitely. They are inviting people to fix it.